# full rank left annihilator matrix

Tags: statistics, matlab

Suppose I have a matrix A= g=[Vfc/(x1*Cdc),x4/(x1*Cdc),-x3/Cdc;0 0 0;0 0 x1/Lcpl;0 -1/Cb 0] and I want to find the full rank left annihilator matrix B such that B*A=0. I am using MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix $B$ cannot be full rank. If this were the case, then $A=0$, which is apparently excluded.

Comment: I got a solution by John D'Errico  B=null(A')' which gives B=(0 1 0 0). it gives B*A=0